# Python3 CSV reader Unicode Decode error

Tags: python, csv, unicode, encoding

I have a huge csv file in utf8 encoding, but some columns with encoding that differs from main file encoding. It looks like:

*input.txt* in UTF-8 encoding:

```
a,b,c
d,"e?",f
g,h,"kü"
```

same *input.txt* in win-1252

```
a,b,c
d,"eü",f
g,h,"kÃ¼
```

Code:

```
import csv

file = open("input.txt",encoding="...")
c = csv.reader(file, delimiter=';', quotechar='"')

for itm in c:
    print(itm)
```

and standart python3 csv reader generates encoding error on such lines.I can not just ignore reading this line but I need only always good encoded "someOther" column.

Is it posible using standart csv reader to split somehow CSV data in some "bytes mode" and then convert each array element to normal python unicode string, or should I implement my own csv reader ?

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Development\t.py", line 7, in <module>
    for itm in c:
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 11: invalid start byte
```

Comment: I think `encoding="..."` would cause problems.

Comment: its pseudocode , I want just to mention that  both utf-8 or ascii or some special encoding will not work.

Comment: What exactly is the error? Can you post the traceback? Is the error in the CSV reader, or is it when you try to print the row?

Comment: Just copy paste your csv, then opened it without encoding params, csv.reader on it without del/quote. And it works. I mean i dont get error

Comment: I have added traceback to the question

Comment: @pltrdy: You can't copy csv from this page. It loses information about encoding.

Comment: I think this is an interesting question but I don't have the time to work up an answer atm.  Set the encoding to "replace" and your file will  load but characters that are "difficult" will be replaced with ``?``.  If you look at https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html it is probably possible to write your own codec.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How sure are you that your file is UTF8 encoded?

For the small sample that you've posted UTF8 decoding fails on the `ü` which is "LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS". When encoded as ISO-8859-1, `ü` is `'\xfc'`. Two other possibilities are that the CSV file is UTF-16 encoded (UTF-16 little endian is common on Windows), or even Windows-1252.

If your CSV file is encoded in one of the ISO-8859-X family of encodings; any of ISO 8859-1/3/4/9/10/14/15/16 encode `ü` as 0xfc.

To solve, use the correct encoding and open the file like this:

```
file = open("input.txt", encoding="iso-8859-1")
```

or, for Windows 1252:

```
file = open("input.txt", encoding="windows-1252")
```

or, for UTF-16:

```
file = open("input.txt", encoding="utf-16")    # or utf-16-le or utf-16-be as required
```

Comment: You are right i can use some encoding like iso and then determine encoding for each column separately.

Comment: @OlegGolovanov: my point was that the whole file would be encoded in one of the suggested encodings. It's unlikely that multiple encodings would be present in the same file. It's also possible (I've updated my answer) that the file is UTF-16 encoded.

Comment: "in one of the suggested encodings ." It is not unlikely - it is my case. This file is about 1.5GB and all fields are encoded in UTF-8 but some columns are urls that scrapped from Web and they are written "as it is" - this causes a problem. I can't regenerate this file - it is my input.

Comment: i suppose in your case the best way to deal with it is to flatten the file to utf8 as it is scraped